# Capture MouseExit Event on EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I know there is the mouseEnter() function in emberjs, but I have failed to find a way to capture the mouseExit event.
I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want `mouseLeave()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have just discovered this: http://pierrel.posterous.com/ember-js-view-events
EmberJS is fantastic, but it needs A LOT of documentation :(

Comment: @YiannisGkoufas it sure does! I'd recommending just checking out the Ember.js source for this sort of thing at the moment, it's pretty readable. Hopefully the documentation will start coming together soon.